# How to create a private endpoint for azure redis cache using terraform?

Tags: azure, redis, terraform

I have created the private endpoint using terraform in azure redis cache.

Here's the relevant part of my Terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


locals {
  redis_name = "my-private-endpoint"
  resource_group     = "my-resource-group"
  location = "eastus"
}


resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = local.redis_name
  location            = local.location
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "akhil-obeliskredis-cache-testing-connection-private"
    private_connection_resource_id = data.azurerm_redis_cache.example.id
    subresource_names              = ["redisCache"]
    is_manual_connection           = false

  }
  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "default"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
  }

}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "privatelinktest.redis.cache.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = "cvad-int-us-k8s-rg-a"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "aks-subnet"
  virtual_network_name = "cvad-int-us-vnet-a"
  resource_group_name  = "cvad-int-us-k8s-rg-a"
}


data "azurerm_redis_cache" "example" {
  name                = "akhil-obeliskredis-cache-testing"
  resource_group_name = "my-resource-group"
}
```

Once private endpoint is created I am facing the issue when I did netcat on the network:

```
nc: getaddrinfo for host "akhil-obeliskredis-cache-testing.redis.cache.windows.net" port 6380: Name or service not known
```

I see one difference. In terraform creation fqdn is not creating and when I created manually from azure portal fqdn is creating and it is working with out any error

Using Terraform
[image]

Manually Creating from azure portal - After that when I p
[image]

Please guide me on what might be missing when I try to create a private endpoint for Azure Redis Cache using Terraform.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the value of `azurerm_private_endpoint.example.private_dns_zone_configs.0.record_sets.0.fqdn`?

Comment: @MattSchuchard. I am getting the error when I am printing: The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the collection has no elements.

So I am here sharing the output of azurerm_private_endpoint.example.private_dns_zone_configs: "private_dns_zone_configs" = tolist([])

Comment: Then this may be an issue in the provider or Azure API if you are confident in your usage/interfacing with Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several resources that needs to be configured correctly for this to work:

- Private Endpoint
- Private DNS Zone
- DNS Zone Group
- VNet Link

Is your Vnet linked to the private DNS zone? I don't see a Vnet link resource in your code.

"`azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link`" enable DNS resolution and registration inside Azure Virtual Networks using Azure Private DNS.

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "test"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
}
```

Refer: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found the solution on the next day when I posted question, But forgot to update here. Thanks again for helping here.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following approach to use Private Endpoint with Redis Cache:

```
module "redis_cache" {
  source = "../shared/redis"

  env_config = local.env_config
  config     = local.redis_config
}

module "redis_cache_endpoint" {
  source = "../shared/network/private_endpoint"

  depends_on = [
    module.redis_cache,
    data.azurerm_subnet.bkend
  ]

  env_config = local.env_config

  config = {
    connected_resource      = module.redis_cache.redis_config.id
    endpoint_name           = "${module.redis_cache.redis_config.redis_cache_name}-pep"
    service_connection_name = "${module.redis_cache.redis_config.redis_cache_name}-sc"
    subnet_id               = data.azurerm_subnet.bkend.id
    subresource_names       = ["redisCache"]
  }
}

module "redis_cache_private_network_a_record" {
  source = "../shared/private_dns/private_dns_a_record"

  depends_on = [
    module.redis_cache,
    module.redis_cache_endpoint
  ]

  providers = {
    azurerm = azurerm.hubdns
  }

  env_config = local.env_config

  config = {
    a_record_name         = module.redis_cache.redis_config.redis_cache_name
    private_dns_zone_name = "privatelink.redis.cache.windows.net"
    private_ip_address    = [module.redis_cache_endpoint.config.private_ip_address]
    ttl                   = 3600
  }
}
```

I have everything config driven and it is working fine for me.